# Get content of div from ajaxForm response

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a search form that submits with ajaxForm, and I want to get the html inside of a specific div, and it tried:

```
$(function search() {
$("#socialSearchUsers").validate({ // initialize the plugin
    // any other options,
    onkeyup: false,
    rules: {
        query: {
            required: true
        }
    }
});

$('form').ajaxForm({
    beforeSend: function() {
        return $("#socialSearchUsers").valid();
    },
            success : function(result) {
                var page = $(result);
                var statusText = page.find('#status').innerHTML;
                console.log(statusText);
                $("#results").html(statusText);
           }
});
});
```

but that (in the console) tells me "undefined" (no quotes).

I'm new to JS and JQuery so if there's an easy way to do it I don't know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.innerHTML` is a POJS property, not jQuery.

Try :

```
var statusText = page.find('#status').html();
```